# Remote desktop connection not reflecting last display change until next keypress

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I've got some really weird behavior remoting from one Windows 7 machine to another. In most apps that I'm using across the remote desktop connection, if I'm typing a word the last letter won't show up until I move the mouse around or hit another key (basically force a repaint). I suppose this could be related to some software running on either the remote or local workstation that is interfering with keypresses. Has anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

A refresh problem shouldn't be connected to the presence of a keyboard-hooking software.

Check in Windows Update for an optional update to Remote Desktop on both computers.

Here is a long-shot reference, regarding Auto-Tuning TCP/IP problems:
[Remote Desktop slow problem solved](http://blog.tmcnet.com/blog/tom-keating/microsoft/remote-desktop-slow-problem-solved.asp)